# Offline Catalyst driver

Tags: windows-7, drivers, amd-catalyst

Im trying to install ATI's graphic driver Mobility Catalyst 10.5, but it has no Internet, so I am trying to burn it from my stationary PC and use it at the laptop. However, I can't find a decent version of the thing, not even with the so called "solution pack" which I despise.

Does anyone know where I can get a decent download of an offline installer? just the drivers, no useless software.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/ (you have to be using IE) and search. You could just search for "ATI" or for your particular model of video card. All drivers and software (and updates) that come though the actual Windows Update application in XP, Vista, 7, etc. are listed on this website for download as a simple `.exe` or `.msi` installer.